# Solr facet pagination

Tags: solr, count, pagination, facet

How in Solr I can do pagination over a facet count?, I know that I have the facet.offset to skip records, but how I know how many total records has the facet?

Comment: `facet.query` for "how many total records has the facet"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply Solr Patch [SOLR-2242](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2242) to get the Facet distinct count.
The total count can be helpful to paginate.

Answer (score 0):

In Solr 5.3 and above use facet to get the total number of documents,

for that simply use,

```
facet=on
```

for example

```
http://<solr-url>/select?facet=on&indent=on&q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json
```

then you get a facets object in response, it will look like,

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "rows":"0",
      "facet":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":8,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}
}
```

you get `numFound` from `response`, which is  the total number of records in that solr core

**another way**

if you have any facet query, use,

```
facet=on&json.facet={}
```

for example

```
http://<solr-url>/select?facet=on&indent=on&json.facet={}&q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json
```

then you get a facets object in response, it will look like,

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "json.facet":"{}",
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "rows":"0",
      "facet":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":80,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}},
  "facets":{
    "count":80}}
```

from `facets` object you get `count`, which is the maximum number of records